# VB Script code not calling c# function

Tags: c#, com, vbscript, registry

I have created a C# dll and registerd as Com object. (Used ProgID, Set Comvisible True and Sign the assembly using Strong name).

I am trying to call c# method using the below  vbscript code

```
Option Explicit 
Dim testwfhandler 
Set testwfhandler= CreateObject("CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler") 
If Not testwfhandler Is Nothing Then     
Call testwfhandler.test()     
End If 
Set testwfhandler= Nothing
```

am i missing anything? or am doing anything wrong?

The below is the registry informaton of my registered dll.

[image]

Comment: Do you get an error message? You should try running the script in a debugger and see if testwfhandler gets assigned.

Comment: I am getting the below error "An error occurred while executing the Workflow script. The Script Engine returned the following information: SOURCE: Line = 3 Column = 0 Number = 429 Source = Microsoft VBScript runtime error Description = ActiveX component can't create object: 'CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler' HelpContext = 0 caused by: Microsoft VBScript runtime error and description: ActiveX component can't create object: 'CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler' Source: LogScriptError"

Comment: What argument did you pass to the ProgId constructor when you attributed your class?

Comment: @Chris Dickson:      [ProgId("CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler")] this is my Progid

Comment: Have you resolved this? I'm also having hard time trying to call methods on object exposed via com from script.

Comment: Yes Puterdo,  I have resolved this. Please register your dll using 32bit regasm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have set ComVisible to True for the C# assembly

Register the assembly using:

```
regasm /codebase YourAssembly.dll
```

Then call it as you have above.

Comment: I have set ComVisible to True in Assemblyinfo.cs file and registered the assembly clearly, Please refer my attched screen shot above in the question.

Comment: Screenshot was too small to read.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Do you receive any error when instantiating an instance of the class in C#?

Comment: I am getting the below error "An error occurred while executing the Workflow script. The Script Engine returned the following information: SOURCE: Line = 3 Column = 0 Number = 429 Source = Microsoft VBScript runtime error Description = ActiveX component can't create object: 'CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler' HelpContext = 0 caused by: Microsoft VBScript runtime error and description: ActiveX component can't create object: 'CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler' Source: LogScriptError"

Comment: [ProgId("CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler")] this is my Progid

Comment: What does your method .test() do?

Comment: test() method will create one text file in the server